# Any way to change screen dimensions so the left part of monitor is blank?

Tags: screen, display-resolution

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, but recently the left 5th of my laptop screen stopped working. Is there any way to adjust the screen dimensions so it doesn't use this portion of my screen while I figure things out?

Thanks